# jQuery traversing XML find parent and children from node with spesific value

Tags: jquery, xml, parent, traversal

I need to traverse an XML file and select a specific node  (and all its children) which contains a child node like

```
<ssn>11036026534</ssn>
```

My aim is to read out the data as $('username',this).text() such that I am able to get all child nodes from the selected

```
<person> and down.
```

I have tried multiple ways of traversing, with no success - the most recent:

```
$(xml).each('person').find('ssn'["06106131859"]).parent( function () {
              console.log('ssn match for person')
          });
```

(which also gave me a jquery error) and

```
$(xml).find('ssn[06106131859]').parent().each( function () {...
```

I would greatly appreciate some help to move forward with this..have a great day!

```
<person personIdHRM="10945"></person>
<person personIdHRM="11538"></person>
<person personIdHRM="1346"></person>
<person personIdHRM="23456">
    <authentication>
        <userId>7260132</userId>
        <username>Petter Smart</username>
    </authentication>
    <employments>
        <employment>
        <employeeId>18220</employeeId>
        <employmentPercentage>100.0</employmentPercentage>
        <lastEmployeed>2003-11-12</lastEmployeed>
      <positions>
        <position isPrimaryPosition="false" validFromDate="2015-01-01">
            <positionPercentage>0.0</positionPercentage>
            <positionStartDate>2015-01-01</positionStartDate>
        </position>
        <position isPrimaryPosition="true" validFromDate="2015-01-01">
            <positionPercentage>100.0</positionPercentage>
            <positionStartDate>2015-01-01</positionStartDate>
        </position>
      </positions>
    <startDate>2003-11-12</startDate>
    </employment>
  </employments>
  <familyName>Hanson</familyName>
  <genderCode>FEMALE</genderCode>
  <givenName>Elizabeth</givenName>
  <hrmAuthentications />
  <ssn>06106131859</ssn>
</person>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:has()` to find an element which contains another. Try this:

```
var $persons = $(xml).find('person:has(ssn)');
$persons.each(function() {
    var $ssn = $(this).find('ssn')
    console.log($ssn.text()); // == 06106131859 in your example
});
```

To select a specific `person` by the `ssn` value, try this:

```
var $person = $(xml).find('person:has(ssn:contains("06106131859"))');
```

Comment: Thank you Rory for a quick answer. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. Every person has a ssn (social security number) - but I need to select the person node which has a spesific number like 06106131859. It's like "select every data from person with ssn like '06106131859'